# Why are my DFSDM register bits not changing on my STM32L476?

Tags: c, stm32, bit, cpu-registers

I am facing a problem with the DFSDM (Digital Filter for Sigma-Delta Modulation) of my STM32L476RE. Indeed, despite the fact that I have enabled the clock for the DFSDM, all the registers related to the my filter (in the code below: `DFSDM1_Filter1->...`) never change when I set a bit, whereas the registers related to my channel `DFSDM1_Channel1->...` do change well. As setting the clock is usuallythe solution for this kind of problem, I am stuck because, as I said, my clock is already enabled for DFSDM. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

```
// Enable DFSDM clock
RCC->CCIPR &= ~RCC_CCIPR_DFSDM1SEL;     // Choose PCLK2 as clock
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_DFSDM1EN;   // Enable DFSDM clock

// Make sure DFSDM is disabled
DFSDM1_Channel0->CHCFGR1 &= ~DFSDM_CHCFGR1_DFSDMEN;

// Channel 1
DFSDM1_Channel1->CHCFGR1 &= ~DFSDM_CHCFGR1_CHINSEL; // Select own input (DATIN1)
DFSDM1_Channel1->CHCFGR1 &= ~DFSDM_CHCFGR1_DATMPX;  // Data is taken from DATIN1 as 1 bit values
DFSDM1_Channel1->CHCFGR1 |= (0x01 <<2U);            // Use internal clock for SPI format
DFSDM1_Channel1->CHCFGR1 |= (0x00 <<0U);            // Strobe data on rising edge
DFSDM1_Channel1->CHCFGR1 |= DFSDM_CHCFGR1_CHEN;     // Enable channel 1

// Filter 1 -> Channel 1, continuous regular conversion
DFSDM1_Filter1->FLTCR1 |= (0x01 <<24U);             // Regular channel 1
DFSDM1_Filter1->FLTCR1 |= DFSDM_FLTCR1_FAST;        // Fast mode enabled
DFSDM1_Filter1->FLTCR1 |= DFSDM_FLTCR1_RCONT;       // Continuous mode
DFSDM1_Filter1->FLTCR1 |= DFSDM_FLTCR1_RDMAEN;      // Enable DMA requests on regular conversion
DFSDM1_Filter1->FLTFCR |= ( 0x02   <<29U);          // Select Sinc2 filter mode
DFSDM1_Filter1->FLTFCR |= ((1023) <<16U);           // with FOSR  = 1024
DFSDM1_Filter1->FLTFCR |= ((255)  <<00U);           // with IOSR = 256
DFSDM1_Filter1->FLTCR1 |= DFSDM_FLTCR1_DFEN;        // Enable filter

// Global enable for DFSDM interface
DFSDM1_Channel0->CHCFGR1 |= DFSDM_CHCFGR1_DFSDMEN;

// Start conversion
DFSDM_Filter1->FLTCR1 |= DFSDM_FLTCR1_RSWSTART;
```